# ngx-owl-carousel case of a single item which take all width

Tags: html, css, angular, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

the ngx-owl-carousel items don't have css property maximising width for responsivity aim, I use the following custom options

```
customOptions: OwlOptions = {
loop: true,
margin: 10,
navSpeed: 700,
responsive: {
  0: {
    items: 1
  },
  400: {
    items: 2
  },
  740: {
    items: 3
  },
  940: {
    items: 4
  }
}
};
```

the probelm is that in case when I have just one element to show, this last will take all parent width; is there an option to tell owl-carousel to consider the calculated width ?
Thanks

Comment: try creating a demo on stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to have `auto-width` owl items
and the stage container to be the total of the widths ?

I tried to apply css on stage

`display:flex-inline`

and

`owl-itemswidth:auto`

but the sliding does not move with the owl items size, it leaves an empty space
on the end of carousel, which I think is the sum of the items width subtracting
the stage width.

Answer (score 0):

Ahm! Here I am.. so I will answer my question ^^'
the 'autoWidth:true' property didn't work, so I applied css on owl-item class as below using ::ng-deep ;)

```
owl-carousel-o {
 ::ng-deep{
  .owl-stage{
    .owl-item{
      width: auto!important;
    }
  }
 }
}
```